# glRotatef moves the axes

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying OpenGL for the first time, so I want to code a simple program that displays a box and lets me move the camera.

As there is no such thing as a camera in OpenGL, I just simulate every "camera movement" I want by making the whole world move in the exact opposite way. It goes well until I get to rotations.

What happens is that whenever I rotate the world (`glRotatef(10, 0, 1, 0);`) the axes get rotated as well, so when I try to apply other transformations, such as  (`glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);`) that would before move the world closer to the camera, it now moves in a totally different direction.

How should I proceed to solve that?

Comment: reverse the operations

Comment: Oh I see, If I first reverse the rotations, then transform, then apply the rotations again the problems' gone. But then I run into a totally different problem. Although it it's ridiculously simple to keep track of what rotations you've performed on each axis so that you can reverse it, it's not so simple to keep track of the order, and the order actually matters. I know there is a different technique for that, are quaternions the way to solve it?

Comment: the camera you are looking for is GL_PROJECTION matrix ... do not mess with the world just move camera position so rotation/movement of cammera will not affect world object global position

Comment: @Spektre: **No!!!** The Projection matrix *is not the camera*! The projection matrix is, if you want to stay in the camera picture, the *lens* of the camera. *Never* use the projection matrix to alter the point of view; if you do it anyway you'll end up with broken illumination.

Comment: @datenwolf projection matrix is the camera position and also the lens configuration (if any non orthogonal projection used) so movement of camera is the same as changing the origin of projection matrix (elements 12,13,14 in global space) this of course change the illumination of scene as it would change with the movement of real camera. the same goes for rotation so why NOT? in my opinion for moving around world you have to move camera(Projection matrix) not all the world objects !!!

Comment: @Spektre: No it's not. Normals are transformed by the transpose inverse of the modelview matrix (and the model view matrix only!) and illumination calculations happen *before* the application of the projection matrix in view space (it should be a strong hint that the result of the modelview transformation is called the *view* space). If you use the projection matrix to move around the point of view you're completely throwing off the illumination calculations of OpenGL. *Now speak with me:* **The projection matrix must not be used for moving the point of view, or bad things will happen!**

Comment: @Spektre: And if you don't believe me, here it is from the horse's mouth, the *official* OpenGL FAQ on the topic: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm#view0030  and regarding your *really* **BAD** suggestion, **read this**: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/projection_abuse.php

Comment: @datenwolf aaah now I get it what you are writing about ... I am not using OpenGL light model ... using mostly GLSL for that and there I handle matrices myself so its not a problem. But it can be done also with fixed pipeline this way , light sources position an or directions must be updated accordingly. When you use GL_MODELVIEW for both camera and object transformations then it is a mess and cause exact same problems as this question is about. (still can be done with 2 matrices and multiply them together before any use but that is +1 matrix/matrix multiplication for every object on scene)

Comment: Think of a sphere where there is a camera on its surface looking at its center. With your movements, calculate the location of the camera on the sphere and use `gluLookAt` to find and apply the transformation matrix.

Comment: @Spektre: doing everything in just the modelview does not cause "a mess". You can precalculate the transform using a proper matrix library and then pass that to OpenGL using `glLoadMatrix` – or `glUniformMatrix` if you're using shaders. Also you should avoing any calculations in the shader which you can precalculate on the CPU. That is for the simple fact, that doing it in the shader will spread out a redundant calculation over all shader executions (which can be a lot).

Comment: @Spektre: Some drivers try to mitigate that by optimizing out the calculation from the shader, but that requires a full recompilation of the shader everytime a uniform's value changes. NVidia's drivers are known to having done that, which caused horrible performance on `glUseProgram` calls. To make a long story short: Always coalesce the full model space to view transform into a single matrix and pass that to the shader. You can also calculate a coalesced model space to projection transform and pass that as well, but depending on the actual shader you might need the intermediate step.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could use matrices to accumulate the transforms of your camera, just like OpenGL does.

But instead of using glRotate or glTransform, you could use a vector math library (i.e.: GLM) and apply analog operations (i.e.: glm::rotate, glm::translate) on a matrix variable (i.e: glm::mat4) you would call the 'local transforms' of your camera object.

Whenever you want to apply transforms on a different space (i.e.: (1,0,0)(0,1,0)(0,0,-1)) you just use a plain new matrix (just like glPopMatrix would do), something you would call 'world transform'.

At the end of each frame you would multiply both matrices (local * world) and use this result to feed OpenGL with a view matrix (i.e.: glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadMatrix(&(local * world)[0]);)

Oh, and don't forget to reset your 'world transform' matrix at the end of your frame.